# Select a specific time between set interval into TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

Hey I want to implement time selection functionality in `TimePickerDialog`. User can select any time between 3PM to 6PM. Other times are not allowed to select. How can I do this functionality?

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try overriding the [onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#onTimeChanged%28android.widget.TimePicker,%20int,%20int%29) method and doing your validation there.

The other option would be to handle it in the [`TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html) listener but this only occurs after the dialog is closed.

Comment: Thanks Cory.. Actually I forgot to check this method.